# I can't install anything on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

My internet dropped while I was updating. Suddenly I couldn't install or upgrade anything. When I do this message loops and eats my RAM until I have to reset:

```
`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3/12/0-57-generic`
```

When I run `sudo apt-get xxxx` it gives me:

```
`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
```

`dpkg --configure -a` causes the same infite loop above.

Any ideas? I considered reinstalling but I don't have the installation disk and I have a data cap on my internet and can't download the iso.

EDIT1:

It seems that `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` was causing problems. I had previously added lines to this file to fix my wifi, which I have now removed. Now I get this output recurring:

`Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done`

I've been running it for a few hours and it keeps spitting out the same thing.

EDIT 2:

I have decided to reformat and install another distro. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the exact output of `dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: I ran it overnight and got this looping endlessly: imgur.com/NwUpLqY

Comment: Please post program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](/q/420981/175814). Also, [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Going back to the issue at hand: what's the content of `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, the file mentioned all over the program output, that you included in your image? Please include it in your question as well.

Comment: I have decided to reformat and install another distro. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the initramfs is a bit a lenghty process. And depending on how fast your system is, it can takeup to minute. Upon each new Kernel installation it has to be created newly. *Let the process finish* - I admit it's confusing if you don't see a progress bar!

Further reading: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs)!

`man update-initramfs` explains a little bit about the process.

You can also run the command on it's own:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

If you get errors just post them. No need to install newly. :-)

Comment: Could you please add a link to the mentioned bug report?

Comment: @Germar - ooops - just reran the command - and obviously I mixed this this up with my old machine where I saw this in the virtual terminal during the boot-process in Wily. Since packagr-managers hide more+more information-it would only be visible in the terminal or in the busybox of Synaptics. Well it would be worth a bug-report. Thanks for asking -  firstly I saw this progressbar with Knoppix-CD during the boot process. Tks for improving the link.

Comment: I always wonder why they don't add a hook for `update-initramfs` and run it for all new/changed kernels at once after installation process. But that's off topic here.

Comment: Just created a [bug-report] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core/+bug/1517305 (Visibility update-initramfs)

@germar update-initramfs will run autmatically, not though if it gets interrupted by shortage of electricity or false (but in this case understandable) user action.  It may even run twice - which is due to a bug in ntfs-3g (which sadly won't have the bugfix backported - *sigh*), but as you said this gets <OT> here. So it's quite nice to be remembered on starters impressions & thanks for confirming this bug-report. That kind of the idea behind OSS

Comment: I ran it last night and it's just stuck on this. It keeps giving the same error messages: http://imgur.com/NwUpLqY

Comment: Looks to me like the system was messed with inappropiate use of _sudo_. But I'd like to wait on somebody elses opinion. Also noting that _update-initramfs_ has succeded.

Comment: I have decided to reformat and install another distro. Thanks for your help.